# Running discord.py commands inside terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have created a discord.py bot and would like to be able to run a command from my terminal, as well as discord. In my terminal I would like to be able to write: `send_something {guild} {a channel id} {word}`, which would send `{word}` to a channel that I inputted.

Command Example:

```
@bot.command()
async def send_something(ctx, guild, channel_id, something):
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, id = channel_id)
    await channel.send(something)
```

How would I make it so I could achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to get your terminal input with some method like `input()`, maybe an async alternative if required, then interpret the string you get how you need it (e.g. by splitting it up and taking each part as a parameter) and use this data to call a function or the bot directly. Edit: how you make the bot send a message is described in the [discord.py doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), if you don't already know how to do it anyways.

Comment: @B1TC0R3 I could use ```term_input = input('>>> ').split(' ')``` and pass them in as such, but wouldn't the first parameter be ctx, which because I'm running through the terminal I cannot get. I believe it is required for a ```commands.Bot``` to have some context.

Comment: Hmm, i don't actually know, never have been in that situation with my bot, sorry. First idea that came to my mind tho is to just copy that from another point in the application where you can access it, but i don't know whether that'll work.